# New domain on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs app running on elastic beanstalk. I have a domain registered through GoDaddy and a cname that points to `myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

1) Can I point my domain to aws nameservers, instead of mapping that domain to the domain that eb has set up?

This is how I would like to set up my domain, but when I attempted to, it wouldn't work (and I'm not sure why). I checked DNS propogation, and things looks good, but when browsing to my domain, things wouldn't work.

2) Can I set up subdomains to work with elastic beanstalk? (eg. sub.example.com)

I read somewhere that subdomains cannot be set up in elastic beanstalk, but I don't understand why this would be. I'd like to have one app running at sellers.example.com and one at buyers.example.com. Can I do this with eb? If not, can I set this up on an ec2 instance and configure it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), if elasticbeanstalk.com name servers will respond to requests for domains under elasticbeanstalk.com domain.
You can checkout the following guide on how to setup your custom domain name to point to your elastic beasntalk app:

http://compositecode.com/2014/01/23/mapping-domain-names-w-name-com-and-amazon-route-53/

For (2), if you have two environments myenv1 and myenv2 then you can set up custom cname prefixes for each environment like myenv1.elasticbeanstalk.com and myenv2.elasticbeanstalk.com. What kind of subdomains would you prefer?
If these are sub domains under your own domain, I guess you could set them up depending on your DNS hosting provider.